# create tables response error，mysql version5.5

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `sa_report` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `content` longtext,
  `sa_city_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `create_time` datetime(1) NOT NULL,
  `update_time` datetime(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '更新时间',
  `verify_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `delete_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sa_report_type_id` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '帖子类型，救助还是宠物日记',
  `sa_user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sa_user_re[ort` (`sa_user_id`),
  KEY `sa_report_type_forgkey` (`sa_report_type_id`),
  KEY `sa_report_city_key` (`sa_city_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `sa_report_city_key` FOREIGN KEY (`sa_city_id`) REFERENCES `sa_city` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `sa_report_type_forgkey` FOREIGN KEY (`sa_report_type_id`) REFERENCES `sa_report_type` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `sa_user_re[ort` FOREIGN KEY (`sa_user_id`) REFERENCES `sa_user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

MySQL version 5.5
after execute ：

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near '(1) NOT NULL,    `update_time` datetime(1) DEFAULT
> NULL COMMENT '更新时间',

how to resolve this question，please help me

Comment: Update 2 line: create_time datetime NOT NULL,
  update_time datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '更新时间',

Comment: Please keep in mind that MySQL 5.5 is pretty outdated. Maybe you are facing any bug that is fixed in a later version?

Comment: DATETIME [(microsecond precision)] didn't appear until 5.6. if you need such precision you need to upgrade. if you attempt to run your code https://dbfiddle.uk/Mhm7SLGP the query fails -change to 5.6 and happy days..

Comment: But keep in mind MySQL 5.6 is also old and out of support. MySQL 5.7 will be out of support by October 2023. You need to keep up to date if you want to use features of current versions and avoid old bugs and security vulnerabilities.